# TrustedInstaller is preventing registry writes to HKCR\DirectShow\MediaObjects\Categories

Tags: windows-7, wix, windows-installer, directshow, wix3

I'm trying to install a DMO which requires me to write to `HKCR\DirectShow\MediaObjects\Categories\57f2db8b-e6bb-4513-9d43-dcd2a6593125`, this registry path is protected by TrustedInstaller and it seems that this protection is new in Windows 7 (it work on previous platforms).

How am I suppose to install DMOs?

There are plenty of places that suggest to take ownership on the this registry key but this just doesn't feel right.

BTW, were using boilerplate Wix3 to write the registry values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Installer cannot be used to update Windows. I know it sounds funny but Windows Installer is for "applications" and the Trusted Installer is for "the operating system". To update pieces of the operating system, you need to use an operating system service pack or KB.

If this is a documented place in the registry that you are supposed to be able to extend then I would guess it would be necessary to contact Microsoft about the key being protected. My guess would be that it is a bug.

If it is a bug in Windows then Microsoft hopefully would provide a work around or fix. Maybe the answer is to take ownership of the registry but I agree that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Just one note, it seems as if the permission was on RC and on RTM of windows 7 it was removed :)

Very interesting and hope i will not encounter any more protected real registry

Comment: Good. That means it was almost certainly a bug in RC that was fixed in RTM. Whew.