# Modifying permissions on a registry key when Administrator has read-only rights

Tags: .net-core, winapi, registry

I'm trying to add a value to this windows key while running elevated (Administrator):

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing

By default, Administrator only has read permissions to this key. I was thinking of using AddAccessRule() to add myself to that key temporarily, but I cannot do this because in order to use AddAccessRule(), I first need to open the key with "write" access, hence I'm caught in a loop here. These are the current permissions:

[image]

This is the code that doesn't work, obviously, because OpenSubkey() fails.

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing", true))
{
   var current = key.GetAccessControl();
   var user = ...;
   current.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user, RegistryRights.WriteKey, AccessControlType.Allow));
   key.SetAccessControl(current);
   key.SetValue("TestValue", 1);
}
```

How should I work myself into that key, so I can write a value there?

Comment: The key probably requires some priviledges, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467909/how-to-write-in-a-registry-key-own-by-trustedinstaller and this for .NET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528888/how-to-enable-the-secreateglobalprivilege-in-net-without-resorting-to-p-invoke

Answer (score 1):

You need to take ownership of the key.

In windows each process has a [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-tokens) that determines the operations the process can perform. By default some privileges are disabled (even when the process is running as elevated) and must be enabled explicitly. The [SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants) is disabled by default.

The answer to that question explains how to change acquire the privilege to change ownership: [How do I programmatically give ownership of a Registry Key to Administrators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448390/how-do-i-programmatically-give-ownership-of-a-registry-key-to-administrators).
It uses a TokenManipulator class mentioned in another answer: [How do you take file ownership with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031552/how-do-you-take-file-ownership-with-powershell/17047190#17047190)

After acquiring the SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege you can call [SetOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setowner?view=net-7.0) method then [AddAccessRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.registrysecurity.addaccessrule?view=net-7.0)